# Ionic -Typeerror: .then() is not a function

Tags: asynchronous, ionic-framework, promise, ionic2

I have tried to get data from assets/data/people-data.json in Ionic. In my providers/people-data.ts

```
getLocalData(){
 try{
  this.http.get('assets/data/people-data.json').map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
   return data;
  });
 }
  catch (error) {
   console.log("Error in httprequest");
   return this.data;
 }
 return this.data;
}
```

In my search.ts page(where I need the data to be published)
the code is as follows

```
generateData() {
 try {
  this.peopleData.getLocalData().then((result) =>{
   console.log("data recieved")
  });
} catch (error) {
   console.error("Couldnot fetch data",error);
  }
}
```

Comment: you have mixed observables and promises..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `getLocalData` should return a `Promise` but its actually returning `undefined` (or whatever `this.data` is, at the start of `getLocalData`).

---

Following will work fine. Here, `getLocalData` returns an observable and `generateData` subscribes to it.

```
getLocalData(){
    return this.http.get('assets/data/people-data.json').map(res => res.json())
}

generateData(){

    this.peopleData.getLocalData().subscribe(
        (result) =>{
        console.log("data recieved")
    }, (err)=>{
            console.log("Error in httprequest");
        }
    );
}
```

---

**Problem in your code:**

`Observables` and `Promises` are two patterns used to deal with asynchronous code (Others are: `callbacks`, `asyn-await`).

An `Observable` and `Promise`, both are Javascript `Object`. Both are like a proxy for a value which will be arriving later in time.
    When the value has arrived (its called resolved value), you use `.subscribe()` if you are extracting resolved value from `Observable` but `.then()` if you are using extracting resolved value from `Promise`.

In your case `this.http.get('assets/data/people-data.json')` returns an `Observable`. Also `this.http.get('assets/data/people-data.json').map(res => res.json())` returns modified `Observable`. But you trying to use `.then()` to extract it, which is not correct.

Also, you were returning, `observable.map().subscribe()` which does **Not** return an Observable, rather a subscription Object. This is a common gotcha by beginners.

`Promises` and `Observables` are deceptively similer. Better to learn them to some extent before using in your code.

Comment: No. Try catch only work for synchronous code. Dont put try catch in `getLocalData`. Just run my code, as it is.

Comment: thank you dasfdsa. Its working. It will be greatly appreciated if you tell my what was the mistake in my code.Thank you in advance

Comment: Edited the explanation.